# OpenCV iterate over columns

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator

I am trying to iterate over the columns of a matrix (e.g. its a bunch of column vectors that are concatenated into a matrix and I'd like to operate on each column vector separately). It is pretty easy to do this using a for loop:

```
for(int n = 0; n < mat.cols; n++)
{
    cv::Mat c = mat.col(n);
    // do stuff to c
}
```

But I'd like to do it using iterators if possible so that I can using std::accumulate or std::transform to simplify my code.

so Im basically looking for something like

```
for each Mat c in mat.columns
```

`Mat` has `begin<>` and `end<>` function but as far as I know it can only be used to iterate over single elements.

Can this be done somehow?

Just to be clear I'd like to write

```
cv::Mat input;

cv::Mat output = std::accumulate(input.begincols(), input.endcols(), cv::Mat::zeros(n,k,CV_64F),
[](const cv::Mat &acum, const cv::Mat &column) { return acum + column * 5; });
```

For a simple example.

### Update:

So since this hasn't been answered, if anyone has a home grown solution to provide iterators like this I'd take a look otherwise I might look into it myself if I get the chance

Comment: Isn't this an unfair expectation ? We could write a home grown iterator for a single column - say iterator for col 1 e.g. `int max =  std::accumulate( input.begincols(1), input.endcols(1) );` But, it appears the question expects iterators over all columns. How would `std::accumulate` know when column 0 is done ? Did you really mean this ?

Comment: @Kiran Take a look at my example, the idea is that each column is passed to accumulate as a mat of ts own, the same exact thing that happens in the original for loop that i demonstrate at the top of the post. This would be extremely useful for situations where a set of data points are represented as column vectors in a single matrix. accumulate doesn't need to know anything for this to work

Comment: @MaxEhrlich I realize this might not be the solution you're looking for, but you could [transpose](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transpose) and then iterate over rows instead of columns.

Comment: @mirosval I don't see how that would help, there isn't an iterator for rows either as far as I know

Comment: I don't see the benefit of trying to go with an iterator as opposed to using a for loop?

Comment: @mprat is that how you feel about iterators in general? Because the logic is the same as wanting to use an iterator for a std::vector or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's been about 2 years since I posted this question but I finally got around to writing such a library. You can find it here

https://gitlab.com/Queuecumber/opencvit

It is distributed as an easy to use companion library for opencv under the MIT license. Examples are in the readme and should be very intuitive for people that know their STL. Right now it provides a `column_iterator` and a `row_iterator` but there are many more possibilities. If anyone has suggestions or finds bugs, please leave an issue on the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe overloading the accumulate function can help. Instead of (possible implementation of the standard)

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T std::accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
   for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = init + *first;
   }
   return init;
}
```

You can write your own, accumulate.

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T std::accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, std::size_t incr)
{
   for (; first != last; first += incr) {
        init = init + *first;
   }
   return init;
}
```

To use it for your images. You have to use the steplength (Math::step1() i guess ) for incr. This should work, but i haven't tested it. Please give feedback if it worked for you.

Comment: It would probably work but it's not as clean as having proper iterators for matrix rows and columns and what about `std::transform` or `std::for_each` or `std::find_if`, all of a sudden I'd need to reimplement the entire `<algorithm>` header just for opencv

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, that cv::Mat images can have an offset ( size(row) != step() ). Maybe you want to create a datastructure holding an array of pointers to the start of each row ( created by Mat::ptr for example ), then you can do something like that:

```
std::vector<uchar*> matRows( mat.rows );
// init matRows via mat.ptr
//....

for (auto i : matRows)
    std::transform( i.begin(), i.begin() + mat.cols, i.begin(), my_trafo);
```

STATUS: NOT TESTED